# UIView background color is always white

Tags: iphone, uiview

I am creating UIView as follows on button action :

```
-(IBAction)addSmiley{
    if(kSmiley == FALSE)
    {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, toolbar.frame.origin.y+50, 320, 50);
        viewSmiley = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        [viewSmiley setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];    
        [self.view addSubview:viewSmiley];
        tbl.frame = CGRectMake(tbl.frame.origin.x, 0, 320, tbl.frame.size.height-50);
        kSmiley = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        [viewSmiley removeFromSuperview];
        viewSmiley = nil;
        [viewSmiley release];
        tbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, tbl.frame.size.height+50);
        kSmiley = FALSE;
    }

}
```

I am able to see UIView but with white background. I am not able to set its background color. What might be the reason?

Comment: It seems that `tbl` is overlapping the `viewSmiley`. Please check the frame position by setting breakpoints

Comment: What's the drawing code for the smiley view?

Comment: seems like problem is with frame of views.. not with background color. Print frame in NSLog(@"%f %f",viewSmiley.frame.origin.x, viewSmiley.frame.origin.y)

Comment: You don't want to set your view to nil before you release it - that will leak.

Answer (score 0):

See this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

Try to change color of view after adding as subview.